# Passing an Object between sibling components - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass an object from one sibling to another via a parent.

Sibling one contains a page list:

```
    this.state = {pages: [
        {pageTitle: 'Home', pageDesc:'', items: [], id:''},
        {pageTitle: 'About', pageDesc:'', items: [], id:''},
        {pageTitle: 'Contact', pageDesc:'', items: [], id:''},
        {pageTitle: 'Contact', pageDesc:'', items: [], id:''}
    ]}
```

and a function to receive data from the parent

```
update = () => {
    let newPageList = [...this.state.pages, this.props.addToList];
    this.setState({pages: newPageList})
}
```

Sibling two contains items that need to be added to the above page list when a button is pressed:

```
this.state = {
    pageTitle: 'New page', pageDesc:'New desc', items: [], id:''
}
```

And a function which passes it's state to the parent:

```
addNewPage = () => {
    let info = {...this.state};
    this.props.callBack(info)
}
```

Here's the parent component

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        data: {
            pageTitle: '', pageDesc:'', items: [], id:''
        }
    }
}

updatePageList = (pageAdded) =>{
    this.setState({data:pageAdded});
    console.log(this.state)
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <PageBuilder callBack={this.updatePageList} />
        <PageList addToList={this.state.data} />
        </div>
     )
}
```

Comment: Do you mind clarifying which code belongs to which classes?

Comment: @George could you also let us know where's the problem you are getting

Comment: You already passed your data to `PageList` which seems to be your `Sibling one` and that you've correctly used the `callBack` you passed to `PageBuilder` (which seems to be `Sibling two`). You don't need to manually use `update` as `props` change triggers a re-render, so you only need to directly use the `props`. Can you tell us what your exact problem is?

Comment: it seems you need some way of managing a global state, you can look at [redux](https://redux.js.org) for state management in react. You can achieve two-way binding with the global state and the "adding to list in component 1 from component 2" should be easy

Comment: Question is a bit confusing. Adding all your code with file names and pointing where exactly the problem is will help with identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your exact problem is but I've built an example showing that `ChildOne` adds a list which is then passed to `ChildTwo` via `App` as the parent, and then renders the list into view.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: []
    }
  }
  
  addToList = (data) => {
    this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, data] }, () => console.log('Parent\'s List (from callback):', this.state.list.join(' '))) 
    console.log('Parent\'s List (just after setState):', this.state.list.join(' '))
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('Parent\'s List (componentDidUpdate):', this.state.list.join(' '))
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildOne addItem={this.addToList}/>
        <ChildTwo list={this.state.list}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ChildOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.i = 0;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ChildOne</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.addItem(this.i++)}>Add</button> {/*Note the arrow function inside onClick, it'll error without it*/}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mylist: props.list
    }
  }
  
  //This one!
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({mylist: props.list}, () => console.log('Child Two\'s List (from callback):', this.state.mylist.join(' ')))
    console.log('Child Two\'s List (just after setState):', this.state.mylist.join(' '))
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('Child Two\'s List (componentDidUpdate):', this.state.mylist.join(' '))
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ChildTwo</h1>
        {this.state.mylist.join(' ')}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that child two's list isn't updating when a new item is added. Child two must also have state containing all of the items (this is important for later features in the application). What is the best way to add the props info to state? I defined a function in child two that could update its state but I'm not sure how to call that function when the props change.

Comment: Then you'll need to update your state in `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle function, which will be called automatically upon detecting a change in props. See my edited answer. But if you'll need this kind of interaction to scale for more complex situation, consider using `react-redux`

Comment: That works but the state seems to be one step behind. It seems like this is something to do with setState being asynchronous. According to the React docs, the solution to it is to use a setState callback. Do you know how I would impliment that? (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: It only looked like it's one step behind because, you guessed it, `setState` is asynchronous, but it's not actually one step behind. In this case, you just need to pass the callback as the second parameter of your `setState` (see edited answer). But as the docs said, it's better if you use `componentDidUpdate()` instead of `setState` callback and do your `console.log()` inside this lifecycle.